# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable? What does it mean? do i have to input the number as an int?

Tags: python-3.x

input

```
num = 556887
for i in num:
    print(i)
```

output:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: What were you *expecting* this to do?  The existing answer assumes you wanted to iterate over the digits of the number - but I can imagine other possibilities, and you've given us no hint.

Comment: Please explain what's your expected output/ what you're trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

It means that it is an `int` and that you cannot iterate (use a for loop) through it.
Changing it to a string solves the problem:

```
num = 556887
for i in str(num):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
5
5
6
8
8
7
```